# Rxjs subscribe after catch is not called

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following lines of code:

```
this.initializer.initialize()
    .catch((e) => { console.log('catch'); return Observable.empty() })
    .flatMap(() => { console.log('flatmap'); return this.route.params })
    .subscribe(() => { console.log('subscribe'); })
```

The logged output is

```
catch
```

What could be causing the `flatMap`, and consequently the subscribe to not be called? Not sure what other code could be relevant here, if anything else is needed, I will supply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously caused by `this.initializer.initialize()` emitting an `error` notification (is this intended?).

The `catch` operator reacts only to `error` notifications, not `next` neither `complete`.

The `flatMap()` operator reacts only to `next` notifications, not `error` neither `complete`.

The `subscribe` call as you have it right now only handles `next` notifications. You could rewrite it to handle also `error`s:

```
.subscribe(
  () => console.log('subscribe'),
  err => console.log('error:', err), 
)
```

However you're using `catch` and you basically replace the error with `Observable.empty()` so it never reaches the subscriber so the error handler won't be called anyway.

Comment: You can turn the `error` into `next` with this: `.catch(e => Observable.of(e))`

Comment: If the .catch turns the error into next, shouldn't that make the flatmap be called with my code above?

Your suggestion works, but it leaves me with this ugly code: https://gist.github.com/Burgov/a1c06e79a1d233f90b87ffe32902d9e9, where I have the same handler for next and error.

Comment: That's true, `flatMap` will be called with the error object.

Comment: @BartvandenBurg Can you make a plnkr or jsbin demo? You can use this template http://jsbin.com/rulaxiw/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You're using `Observable.empty()` in `catch` that emits only `complete` notification and no `next` notifications. That's why the `subscribe` handler isn't called. See this http://jsbin.com/yomirij/2/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Ah, is that it... So what should I be using instead?

Comment: I have no idea what your code should be doing. Maybe you want to `Observable.of(err)` like I did here http://jsbin.com/yomirij/2/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Ok, that works indeed. Thanks! Important lesson learned - not everything calls `next`

Comment: By the way I did try at first to exclude the catch and handle everything in the complete, but that basically ended up in the same situation. I now understand that i'd either need to return Observable.empty() from the catch, and handle everything in `complete`, or do Observable.of(err) and handle things in `next`